# How to generate a log file of the windows prompt when I run a bat file

Tags: batch-file, logging, command-line, window

I'm running a bat file in windows. I'm trying to generate a log file of all the output that appears in the command prompt, to have as a document.

Note, Not a log file of the contents of the bat file but of the command prompt that it outputs.

How would I do this? Thanks

Comment: `(call script.cmd)2>&1>"logfile.log"` You also need to understand that any command within the batch file that is being redirected to null, i.e `echo Done >nul` will not be logged to the file as it is explicitly sent to null inside the script. Also `2>&1` is redirecting the stderr stream (`2`) to the stdout stream (`1`), it is important here, seeing as you said you want to log all of the output results to logfile.

Comment: If you don't want the commands from the batch file itself to appear in the log file, make sure that the first command it contains is ```@Echo Off```.

Comment: Thanks, disappointed that the only way to get the log files is from outside the bat file, but appreciate it guys.

Comment: you can log inside of the batch file aswell, @tadm123. the concept is exactly the same as with what I have demonstrated in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirecting to output is done by using `>` or appending to file using `>>`

for [`batch-file`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info), we typically call them.

```
(call script.cmd)2>&1>"logfile.log"
```

or append

```
(call script.cmd)2>&1>>"logfile.log"
```

Note, `2>&1` 2>&1 is redirecting the `stderr` stream `2` to the `stdout` stream `1`, it is important here, seeing as you said you want to log all of the output results to logfile.

So that should also give the clue that you can in fact redirect success (`stdout`) results to one file and failures (`stderr`) to another, i.e

```
(call script.cmd) 1>"Output.log" 2>"Errors.log"
```

Note, some commands and executables sends everything to the `stdout` stream and nothing to `stderr`, example `ping.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a label at the start of the batch file, then use call and redirect the output to a file.
Here is an example from one of my batch files:

```
@echo off
call :script > "C:\path\logfile.txt" 2>&1
exit

:script
rem your script goes here
```

Let's say you have a simple batch file that asks the user for a word then repeats that word such as this:

```
@echo off
set /p input="What word do you want to print? "
echo %input%
```

To make this script output to a file instead of the console window, you would do this:

```
@echo off
call :script > "C:\path\logfile.txt" 2>&1
exit /b

:script
set /p input="What word do you want to print? "
echo %input%
```

This will now output to `C:\path\logfile.txt` instead of the console window.

Comment: Hi Joshua, I don't really understand. So if my bat file is called `my_bat.bat`, I would put `call :my_bat.bat > "logfile.txt" 2>&1`

Comment: and where it says `rem your script goes here` put the contents of the bat file?

Comment: No @tadm123, don't change `:script`. Yes put the content of your bat file there. Also change `exit` to either `exit /b` or `goto :eof`.

Comment: @tadm123 I have edited my answer to respond to your comments. However, Gerhard's answer provides even greater detail, so his is the accepted answer.